# Who put the seals on Lucifer's cage?

Tags: supernatural

I've just read the supernatural wiki on Lucifer's Cage, and it mentions both the cage and the seals are created by God.

That's all well and good but i see no reference to it in the show. I know it was god that cast him out of heaven but I have no reason to believe he caged him too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was referenced in the show on multiple occasions; as the wiki also points out:

> This Cage was designed as a prison immediately after Lucifer's rebellion. After being banished from Heaven for defying God, Lucifer decided to anger God by twisting a Human soul into the first demon. After this, ***God sent Michael to imprison Lucifer***.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: So the cage is Michael's creation?

Comment: Doubtful, since it is also capable of containing Michael *and* Lucifer starting with Season 6. My assumption is that God created the cage, along with the provisions to allow Lucifer to eventually escape (when it was time to begin Armageddon). He then tasked Michael with descending from Heaven to battle Lucifer and put him in the cage.

Comment: Could you fill in some of those references. I spent the last 5-6 weeks watching seasons 1-6 and I didn't pick up any clear references.

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure but I would guess Death? Since they say Death is even more powerful the God.

Comment: Hey Matt, thanks for your answer! As it stands you don't really have much proof. Have you seen the [faq]? Do you have any references?